# Выбор DI: AutoMapper vs Autofac

Tags: c#, automapper

У Марка Симана в книге Внедрение зависимостей в .Net (написана в 2008 году) рассматриваются несколько библиотек DI: StructureMap, Castle Windsor, Unity, Autofac.

И не рассматривается AutoMapper (видимо, его тогда ещё не было?)

Тем не менее, если посмотреть на число скачиваний nuget-пакетов популярность AutoMapper почти в два раза выше чем у Autofac (на конец 2017 года: 14М загрузок у Automapper и 8М у Autofac и Unity, остальные в районе 2М), любопытно понять за счёт чего такая популярность?

Это фреймворк, который умеет больше в плане возможностей, более гибкий и удобный?

Comment: Автомаппер тоже DI умеет? Я думал это только маппер...

Comment: Таки да, автомаппер для автоматических маппингов типа model <-> viewmodel или model <-> dto. От DI там вроде ничего нет.

Comment: Потому же, почему в книге Демидовича "Сборник задач и упражнений по математическому анализу" не учат, как собирать стул и чистить картошку. AutoMapper -- не DI-фреймворк, несмотря на то, что созвучен  по названию с Autofac.

Comment: Во первых, AutoMapper ни разу не DI, во вторых, полулярность при выборе DI фреймворка не имеет особого значения, это больше вопрос личных предпочтений.

Comment: Автомаппер никакого отношения к DI не имеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Automapper** - библиотека для преобразования (mapping) одного объекта в другой при помощи определённых правил.

**Dependency injection** - механизм, который связывает объекты между собой через абстракции, например, через интерфейсы.

Приведу небольшой пример:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IHouseService houseService;

    public ValuesController(IMapper mapper, IHouseService houseService) 
    // объекты в конструктор передаются через DI (в моём случае Autofac) в том числе и интерфейс automapper
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.houseService = houseService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HouseDto Get()
    {
        var house = houseService.GetHouse();
        // Здесь мы преобразуем объект типа House в объект типа HouseDto при помощи Automapper.
        // Настройку маппинга проводим в отдельном файле (HouseProfile) и подключаем через DI
        return mapper.Map<HouseDto>(house);
    }
}

// Файл с настройкой маппинга
public class HouseProfile : Profile
{
    public HouseProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<House, HouseDto>();
    }
}
```